# Rsync only when external drive is connected

Tags: rsync

How can I make rsync happen ONLY if I have my external backup drive connected? When I set a cron job to do this, it worked fine. But, when I disconnected the drive, it went and created a folder /media/ and copied the files.

Answer (score 2):

Just check if the drive is connected **and** mounted before doing the backup.

The command `mountpoint` does that for you. For example:

```
$ mountpoint /media/MyBackup && /path/to/script.sh
```

`script.sh` will then only run if `/media/MyBackup` is a mountpoint.